# Re-use a WebService but with custom endpoint

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, proxy-classes

I'm using a **Web Service** that has a endpoint of `http://api.domain_a.com/` and using **Visual Studio** I can easily generate a proxy class to work with the service easy and simple.

[image]

But I want to create a way that users can use their own service (and access their own data, instead my own) and I wanted to know if there is a way that I can **change** the base URL of the Service **on-the-fly**.

*As an example*

I generate the proxy classes by adding the Web References to my project, but now, per each request **I have a User Name** that I will get the User Settings (witch contains their URL), **how can I** (if it's a possibility) **tell** the generated proxy that I'm using domain `http://domain_b.com/api` instead of the original that I used when adding the Web References?

Do I need to call the service manually? Sending and Receiving XML data? or there is a "switch" that I can use to point to the new URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using .NET 2.0, each of those proxy classes should have a URL property. Simply update the URL property and the proxy will point to the new service.

If you're using WCF then things get a little more complicated, but not by much. You just have to change the Endpoint Address:

```
var service = new ServiceClient();
string url = "http://domain_b.com/api";
EndpointAddress newAddress = new EndpointAddress(url);
service.Endpoint.Address = newAddress;
```